# cant make this delimiter work, java split

Tags: java

I need help making a delimiter for multiple characters

I need a String delimiter for
these characters

> (  )  "  ;  :  ,  ?  !  .

I've tried:

```
private String delimiter = "()\":;,?!.";
private String delimiter = "[()\":;,?!.]";
private String delimiter = "\\(\\)\"\\:\\;\\,\\?\\!\\.";
```

Seems I can only make them work one at a time..
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

If it matters this is how its going into array:

```
foo = line.split(delim);
```

Comment: Thanks guys! that worked, err do you know if its possible for me to split it withought the removal of the character IE   dog! woof = dog! (enter) woof rather than dog (enter) woof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is required between:

`delimiter = "\\(|\\)|\"|:|;|,|\\?|!|\\."`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split on *any* of those characters, you can separate each one with an [*alternation*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): `|`. Otherwise, the string will only be split when *all* of those characters are present.

```
String delimiter = "\\(|\\)|\"|\\:|\\;|\\,|\\?|\\!|\\.";
```

Also, you're unnecessarily escaping a few characters, this would also work:

```
String delimiter = "\\(|\\)|\"|:|;|,|\\?|!|\\.";
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost there with nr. 3

```
@Test
public void delim() {
    String delimiter = "[\\(\\)\"\\:\\;\\,\\?\\!\\.]";
    String[] split = "Hello(World)How:are;You;doing,today?You!sir.I mean"
       .split(delimiter);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
}
```

**Output**

```
[Hello, World, How, are, You, doing, today, You, sir, I mean]
```

You missed the square brackets.

To avoid all the quoting you may use [Pattern#quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

```
String delimiter = "[" + Pattern.quote("()\":;,?!.") + "]";
```

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.
>   This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>   Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.